# How to save/load OpenCV XML/YML

Tags: c++, opencv

I have been working on my FaceRecognizer class for a while and I have my model trained every time I launch from a folder of all my pictures. I recently read on the saving and loading option of OpenCV's faceRecognizer and I failed to make it work because I don't know where to save the yml file. Here is my code. (I used i as a switch). How should I make this work? Thank you!

```
if(i = 0){ //Save the file
        model->save("C:\\Users\\MT\\Desktop\\PhotoDatabase\\trained.yml");
        cout<<"Saved - from C++" << endl;
    }else{
        ifstream trainedModel("C:\\Users\\MT\\Desktop\\PhotoDatabase\\trained.yml");
        if(trainedModel){
            model->load("C:\\Users\\MT\\Desktop\\PhotoDatabase\\trained.yml");
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
```

Comment: The `if(i = 0)` seems very wrong, try `if(i == 0)` instead.

Comment: WOW,thank you! You are a life saver!!!!!!! It works!!! I am a Java Developer so when I make those types of mistakes, the Java Compiler catches it. Can you explain why C++ doesn't catch this as mistake at compile time?

Comment: Not sure exactly why this is not detected, at least with a warning..